# Merge items in list with delimiter python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the following list:

```
[50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 5.0, 200.0, 300.0, 10.0, 400.0]
```

and I would like to merge items in my list using the `:` delimiter, to create the following list:

```
[50.0, 100.0:150.0:5, 200.0:300.0:10.0, 400.0]
```

I would like to use the new list in `numpy.r_`. I have already converted my list from strings to floats so I would like to retain the floats and just add in the `:` delimiter between the appropriate indices. The issue I'm having trouble with is, if I want floats I can't convert the `100.0:150.0:5` interval values, and with my float values I am having trouble adding in the `:` delimiters. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't `100.0:150.0:5` be a string?

Comment: I take in the user supplied list as a string [50.0, 100.0:150:5.0, 200.0:300.0:10.0, 400.0], then split it on the delimiters ',:' so I can convert to floats. Now I want to add back in the ':' delimiter. Numpy_r won't take input as a string, so the intervals 100.0:150.0:5.0 and 200.0:300.0:10.0 can't be strings

Comment: I would like them to be floats. numpy.r_ takes comma separated arrays.

Comment: Means you want to use them to index another array?

Comment: Yes. So after input into numpy.r_[50.0,100:150:5.0, 200.0:300.0:10.0, 400.0] would output [50., 100., 105., 110., 115., 120., 125., 130., 135., 140., 145., 200., 210., 220., 230., 240., 250., 260., 270., 280.0., 290., 400.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about doing:

```
In [152]:  [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 5.0, 200.0, 300.0, 10.0, 400.0]
Out[152]: [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 5.0, 200.0, 300.0, 10.0, 400.0]
In [153]: np.r_[50.0, 100.0:150.0:5.0, 200.0:300.0:10.0, 400.0]
Out[153]: 
array([  50.,  100.,  105.,  110.,  115.,  120.,  125.,  130.,  135.,
        140.,  145.,  200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,
        270.,  280.,  290.,  400.])
```

I added the `:` in the `ipython` editor.  I'm not really doing string operation, e.g. `np.r_['50.0', '100.0:150.0:5.0',...]`.

An equivalent expression uses `slice`:

```
np.r_[50.0, slice(100.0,150.0,5.0), slice(200.0,300.0,10.0), 400.0]
```

or if the list is `ll`:

```
np.r_[ll[0], slice(*ll[1:4]), slice(*ll[4:7]), ll[7]]
```

In an indexing context `[]`, the `a:b:c` expression is translated into a slice object, `slice(a,b,c)`.  `r_` then converts it to a `arange(a,b,c)` and in turn concatenates those.

So effectively the `r_` expression is:

```
np.concatenate([ [ll[0]], np.arange(*ll[1:4]), np.arange(*ll[4:7]), [ll[7]] ])
```

A numpy way of grouping the middle values in to 3's and putting them in slices is:

```
In [166]: [slice(*ii) for ii in np.array(ll[1:-1]).reshape(-1,3)]
Out[166]: [slice(100.0, 150.0, 5.0), slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0)]
```

(this is an alterantive to @Moses's use of `iter`).  But embedding this kind of list in `np.r_` (or even `np.concatenate`) is tricky.

It may be easier to generate the `arange` directly:

```
In [189]: subl = [np.arange(*ii) for ii in np.array(ll[1:-1]).reshape(-1,3)]
In [190]: subl
Out[190]: 
[array([ 100.,  105.,  110.,  115.,  120.,  125.,  130.,  135.,  140.,  145.]),
 array([ 200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,  270.,  280.,  290.])]
In [191]: np.concatenate([[ll[0]]]+subl+[[ll[-1]]])
Out[191]: 
array([  50.,  100.,  105.,  110.,  115.,  120.,  125.,  130.,  135.,
        140.,  145.,  200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,
        270.,  280.,  290.,  400.])
```

Comment: This is really helpful, especially with all of the different ways you're showing how to do this. I think I like the np.r_[ll[0], slice(*ll[1:4]), slice(*ll[4:7]), ll[7]] solution you provided. How might I do this in a loop, say I knew the indices at which I needed ':' delimiters, would it be pretty easy to compose this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have numbers delimited by `:` without wrapping them with `""` (i.e as strings). You can however do what you intend using `slice`:

```
s = [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 5.0, 200.0, 300.0, 10.0, 400.0]

it = iter(s[1:-1])
s[1:-1] = map(slice, *(it,)*3)
print(s)
# [50.0, slice(100.0, 150.0, 5.0), slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0), 400.0]
```

---

And can now be used with `np.r_` and `np.concatenate` as follows:

```
>>> np.concatenate([np.r_[i] for i in s])
array([  50.,  100.,  105.,  110.,  115.,  120.,  125.,  130.,  135.,
        140.,  145.,  200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,
        270.,  280.,  290.,  400.])
```

which yields your desired result.

Comment: This does what I asked for given the list I provided thanks. Is there a way to use indices in the provided example and apply the slices only to the indexed values? I'm curious how the array reads out the actual values too..I notice when I input this into numpy.r_ it provides the array as an object, output like array([50.0, slice(100.0, 150.0, 5.0), slice(200.0, 300.0, 10.0), 400.0], dtype=object). How do I get it to print out all of the actual values in the array for use?

Comment: @user1332577 I've added the part that will help you build the array you want

Comment: Moses, any idea how to implement this for a random set of lists. I.e., the above mapping doesn't work for say a list like [50:100:5,100:200:5,200,300:400:5,500,600:700:10,800,900,1000] or another random list like [50,75,100:200:10,200,300:400:10,400,500,600:800:20,900]. I'm trying to figure out how to make it versatile enough every time

Comment: With original list of strings, yes, I think you could check if an item contains `':'` to determine if it should be used as a slice. If it is, then split it and convert the items to float. Finally, build the slices from the floats

Comment: If the original list is  [50:100:5,100:200:5,200,300:400:5,500,600:700:10,800,900,1000]  I'm splitting it on ',:' using re.split, e.g., array=re.split('(,:)', stringinput). What's hard is mapping back the new array to the original array correctly every time

Comment: I still don't get the structure of the input well. Is it a string or a list of one string or strings? And I think it better if you formulate this as a new question, so you can properly describe what you want in full details